# Your new site design is live!

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see, the new design just went live!

At this point, we are done with major revisions to the design (although you can still report CSS/styling bugs by starting a new post and tagging it with [design](/questions/tagged/design) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)). Thank you for your [valuable design feedback](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/writing-site-design-and-logo-draft) and for your patience while we got this design out for you.

We really hope you like the design!

Comment: Note: We've noticed a display bug with the background color of the Ask Question page (on both the main and meta sites), and are looking into it now.

Comment: ^Closing the loop here to give the update that the ask question page bug has been fixed!

Comment: Very nice design. Congratulations to the team (Staff) and the community.

Answer (score 9):

I have to say I think it looks great! Many thanks to those at SE who put the new theme together.

Answer (score 5):

How about customizing the badge icons?
[image: screenshot]

They could be styled as pencils for example.

Comment: ... or a quill?